# Linq2DB one POCO from multiple tables

Tags: linq2db

I'm POCing a database first application using Linq2DB and I can't seem to figure out the right way to solve this problem. Is there a way to map the results of two tables to one POCO class? Are there any examples out there showing this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by `results of two tables`? Maybe add some sample

Comment: Basically I just meant mapping the results of a join to a single POCO class. So:

SELECT * FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON ID1 = ID2

Comment: @DLuk sorry to tag you again, but is there a way to do this directly with mappings rather than joins? I'm imagining having a class with properties that map to multiple DB tables, but I can't seem to figure out whether this is possible through the mapping API. Looking at FluentMappingBuilder now but haven't found a way to achieve this yet. Thanks!

Comment: @DLuk nvm, I think I was able to figure out what was needed by using associations and .LoadWith(). These are super useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by `result of two tables` you mean result of query over two tables, then you just need to write linq query and select required columns into fields/properties of your class:

```
from t1 in db.GetTable<Table1>()
join t2 in db.GetTable<Table2>() on t1.Key equals t2.Ket
select new ResultClass()
{
    Field1 = t1.SomeField,
    Field2 = t2.SomeOtherField
}
```

Comment: so I'm guessing that in this case you don't add the [Table] attribute to the POCO class?

Comment: Yep. It also could be anonymous class or scalar value if you don't plan to return it from method as-is or use loaded data in method directly

Comment: Thanks for this! I must be thick today, because it took me a while to figure out how to actually implement this. It's not great, because my methods will be huge now with the select statement, but oh well. I guess that's the nature of the DB I'm working with.

Comment: Now I just have to figure out how to parameterize the schema for each request, and I'll be golden!